# React-router-dom redirect not working with withRouter HOC (react-redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-redux

I read whole bunch of posts about withRouter helping with redirection, but for my case it not working. When I ckick on logout link I should be redirected outside of the main application(because we using for authentication external application), but not Redirect with

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, MapDispatchToProps)(Logout))
```

or Link, or a with href to needed url, even window.location not redirect from my rendered Account component. And it is not raises any errors in console. It's even don't shows in browser history. It's just blinks on Account page and thats all.
So how can I redirect user from my application to another external site via react-dom-router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-router-dom` is a package that allows you to create routes inside your SPA (Single Page Application). To redirect to an external website you have two options:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

The first will simulate the behavior of an HTTP request while the second will simulate the behavior of clicking on a link.

Comment: It seems that this is the only working solution. Thanks.

Comment: So should I use one of this options in componentWillUpdate or in another place?

Comment: You can use them anywhere since they are plain JS. Just put them in the function that handles the click on logout button.